# Transferring a very large image from the web to S3 using AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, stream, aws-lambda, large-files

I have access to a 20 GB image file from the web that we'd like to save on S3.

Is it possible to do this with AWS Lambda? From how I understand the situation, the limitations seem to be the following:

- The lambda memory (can't load the whole image into memory)

Now if we decide to stream from the web to S3 (say using `requests.get(image_url, stream=True)` or [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open)..

- the lambda reaching its timeout limit, along with..
- S3 not supporting appending to S3 objects. Thus, succeeding lambda runs to continue "assembling" the image on S3 (where preceding ones left off) will have to load the partial image that's already on S3 into memory, before it can start appending more data, and uploading the resulting larger partial image to S3.

I've also heard of others suggesting to use multi-part uploads. But I'd be happy to know how that's different from streaming, and how that will overcome the limitations listed above.

Thank you!

Comment: You will be required to use Multipart Upload since your file is over 5GB. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/ I personally wouldn't think of using Lambda for this, especially if it's just a one time thing. I'd simply spin up a temporary EC2 server and run a script from there to copy the file over to S3.

Comment: @MarkB You cannot use Lambda for this purpose, reason being limitation on API Gateway to upload data is only 6MB. Spinning up EC2 server is not a scalable solution and file need to be uploaded from web to S3. Spinning up an EC2 server requires more configuration for High Availability.

Comment: @Kannaiyan nobody said they were uploading the file to Lambda or using API Gateway. Lambda would be downloading the file I assume. But I also said Lambda was a bad solution for this, so I agree with you that Lambda shouldn't be used. Regarding EC2 did you not see where I said "If it's just a one time thing"? If this file only needs to be copied to S3 once, then a temporary EC2 server is a perfectly fine solution. There would be no need for "High Availability". If this is a constant recurring task then the question needs more details.

Comment: @MarkB We've considered EC2 if only done once. But this will be more of a recurring regular task of processing images on the GB scale.

Comment: How often? You could certainly spin up and shutdown an EC2 instance on-demand to handle this sort of thing.

Comment: @MarkB Several times a day as a start, but scaling up to dozens of times a day. An EC2 instance with a huge storage capacity should be the way to go then.

Answer (score 1):

Things are much simplified with s3.

Create a lambda to generate pre-signed url for multipart upload.

**Create Multipart Upload:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property

**Create Signed URL with the above Multipart Upload Key:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Use that url to upload multiple parts of your file parallel.
You can also use S3 accelerator for high-speed upload.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT1:**

You can split the file in chunk between 1 to 10,000 and upload them parallelly.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html

If you are doing only one file upload, you can generate the signedurl and multipart in the cli rather than lambda.

If you are doing regularly, you can generate them via lambda.

When you read the file to upload, if you read them via HTTP, read them in a chunk and upload in multipart.

If you are reading the file locally, you can have the starting point of the file for each chunk and upload them with multipart.

Hope it helps.

Comment: For the multipart upload, does this assume that the image is stored somewhere locally? Or can the above solution work on a remote image URL as the source? Just making sure since I'm using a lambda that's all by itself (limited memory and constrained by a timeout) while interfacing only with an image URL somewhere on the internet (containing the 20 GB image) and S3.